# Using OR in List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, boolean-logic

For the life of me I can't figure out why this won't work. I'm trying to get the sum of a list however if the list contains the value 13 that value should be excluded form the sum and so should the following value. For example `[1,13,3]` would be 1 and `[13,2,5]` would be 5.

I have been trying this list comprehension:

```
lst = [3,3,13]
sum([lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)) if not lst[i] == 13 or not lst[i-1] == 13])
```

The OR seems to not be working like I expect. If I remove either part of the OR statement it works exactly as it should. Example

```
>>> lst = [3,3,13]
>>> [lst[i] for i in range(0,3) if not lst[i] == 13]
[3, 3]
>>> [lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)) if not lst[i] == 13 or not lst[i-1] == 13]
[3, 3, 13]
```

Comment: With `or`, your condition will only fail if there are two `13`s in a row.

Comment: `not blah or not bloo` is different from `not (blah or bloo)`. The behavior you're expecting is what the second thing does.

Comment: De Morgan's laws strike again http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Testing some more I think an additional problem is the `lst[i-1]`. When `i == 0` that evaluates to `lst[-1]` which would give me the last value in the list which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your code.

1. If the last element is 13, then the first element with not be added because `lst[0-1] == 13` because of Python's index wrap around.
2. As stated in the comments and in the other answer, you should be using `and`, instead of `or`. This is because of [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Then, the resulting code is

```
sum([lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)) if not lst[i] == 13 and not(i > 0 and lst[i-1] == 13)])
```